# Отсутствует оператор

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{ 
    string path;
    cin >> path;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(path);
}
```

Отсутствует оператор ">>" соответствующий этим операндам.

В чём проблема?

Comment: Все необходимые `#include` прописаны?

Comment: Присоединяю, проверьте все ли #include

Comment: #include <fstream>
#include <iostream> Как в видео по которому делаю

Comment: namespace отсутствует? `std::` либо `using namespace std;`

Comment: namaspace есть.

Comment: А `#include <string>`?

Comment: Ник суггестивный, кстати.

Comment: Всё компилируется без проблем: http://cpp.sh/4rs6d

Comment: После перезагрузки студии всё магией заработало

Comment: @FiftySeventh: Вы что-то выдумываете. Тут нужна не "перезагрузка студии", а `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код на [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh) : http://cpp.sh/4rs6d . Всё без проблем компилируется. Скорее всего у вас указаны не все #include .

Старайтесь в дальнейшем, задавая вопрос, писать полностью тот код, который вы пытались компилировать, тогда отвечающие сразу бы увидели, каких include не хватает.

Comment: Хорошо, на счёт библиотек я понял. Спасибо. А на счёт программы, перезагрузил студию и магией проблема исчезла.

Comment: Такое бывает :) У студии точно периодически всплывает, видимо где-то у неё парсер сошёл с ума... Справедливости ради, стоит заметить, что Qt тоже иногда чудит, пока не перезапустишь, хотя и реже.